# std::default_constructible for templated class parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, default-constructor

I'm fairly new to c++-templates, and at the point where I'm realizing that I'm probably doing template meta-programming. What I want is to achieve the following definition:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// T must be default-constructible
template<class T, std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<T>>>
class PoolAllocator
{
public:
    PoolAllocator(unsigned int numItems);
    ~PoolAllocator();

    T* Alloc();
    void Free(T* item);

private:
    struct mPoolItem
    {
        T          item;
        mPoolItem* next;
    };
    mPoolItem* mpPool;
    mPoolItem* mpFreePointer; // points to the first free element or nullptr
};
```

I want a compile-time check whether or not the provided template type `T` has a default constructor, and otherwise result in a compile error.

Am I using the correct approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::std::enable_if` and meta-programming is generally useful in only one scenario. When you have multiple options (specializations of a class template or overloads) that you want to prune. If we have a simple class template and we want to check a condition about its type (not choose between options, it's either valid or a hard error), I find a `static_assert` generally works better for my needs.

Comment: Good point! Thank you. `static_assert` will cover my needs

Comment: You can’t use `std::enable_if` quite like that anyway: you need a default template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::enable_if` is pointless on a class template. It's useful for overloaded function templates, and less commonly, for partial specializations of a class template; that's where SFINAE applies.

If you simply want to prevent `PoolAllocator` from compiling if `T` is not default-constructible, use `static_assert`:

```
template<class T>
class PoolAllocator {
  static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<T>,
    "Parameter must be default-constructible");
  // The rest of implementation here
};
```